# Validating field's with variable id. How to output errors. jQuery validation plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

**(1)** I have next html:

```
<form method='post' action='' id='#countersForm'>
<label class='error' id='88'></label>
<input id="88" class="counter_input active" type="text" enabled="">
<label class='error' id='89'></label>
<input id="89" class="counter_input active" type="text" enabled="">
</form>
```

I need to validate this fields with [jquery validation plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/).

How I can do this in case that fields are variables? For 1 user id will be 100 and 1000, for another 55 and 123. What jquery code I need to validate this.

```
if($("#countersForm").length)
{
    $("#countersForm").validate({
        rules: {
            "89": {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2
            }
        },
        messages: {
            "89": {
                required: "We need your email address to contact you",
                minlength: jQuery.format("At least {0} characters required!")
            }
        }
    });
}
```

**(2)** In what fields messages from 'messages' section will be printed? How I can specify them? I find many articles about this plugin at all, but there are not many (i still didn't find them) examples with output fields.

Maybe this code will help me:

```
$("#myForm").validate({
    rules: {
        field: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 10,
            alphanumeric: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        field: {
            required: 'This is required.',
            minlength: 'Please enter at least 10 characters.',
            alphanumeric: 'No special characters.'
        }
    },
    errorPlacement: function(error) {
        $("#response").html(error);
    }
});
```

But it place error in `#responce` element. I need to output error near input field. Can I somehow get id of current-validating-element and output error to label, connected to this element?

Comment: `Id` must be unique use class instead

Comment: Well ok. It is simple code, I am using both `id` and `class` attributes in each input. I will edit my question better.

Answer (score 0):

Try [.insertafter()](http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/)

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        error.insertAfter(element);
}
```

---

**ID** must be unique use classes instead .

Two elements should not have same id.

Read [Two HTML elements with same id attribute: How bad is it really?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/127178/)

Comment: What do you mean writing this: " ID must be unique use classes instead "?

Comment: @SharikovVladislav Two elements should not have same id.

Comment: Hm. Maybe I did a mistake. Id are not equal. Check question now.

Comment: Will `$('label#xx').find.html(error)` work? I don't need insertAfter input, I need to output message into label, connected with each field. How I can get id of current-validating field to do this?

Comment: @SharikovVladislav above code will create a label itself you don't need to add label .

Comment: Thank you. Ok. I will use `insertBefore();`. But there are no answer about how to validate fields with id like '89', '90' etc.

Comment: @SharikovVladislav It is possible but it will be very messy.